selecting all faces and then re-positoning that selection equally amongst all faces
At the very beginning of this youtube tutorial tutorial the creator selects all faces and then brings the edges all equally in a bit to create this equally lowered road,
how can I replicate that process there?
before:

after:

just looking for the hotkeys/menu path. thanks in advance

Inset operation: use the I key.
For more information about inset options, you can refer to the documentation.

thats going in the right direction, but sorry for my lack of knowledge, theres more I need to know. Firstly why does his inset ignore the boundaries of the inner edges? See how the selected area does not get inset at the crossroads, and only at the outside edges
